# create Rmd template that auto generates the date just like default Rmd template

Tags: r, knitr, r-package

In RStudio, when I open a new R Markdown file, the default format has this nice feature where it writes in today's date into the YAML.

I would love for my custom templates in my own R packages to offer this feature but I cannot seem to do better than

```
---
title: ""
author: "Me"
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%B-%d")`'
output: html_document
---
```

The problem with '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%B-%d")`' is that it rewrites the date every time I knit the file, which is undesirable for my workflow. I'd rather maintain the date that the file was initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `file.info` like this

```
---
title: "title" 
author: "Me"
date: '`r file.info("date.Rmd")$ctime`'
output: html_document
---
alternatively...
`r file.info(knitr::current_input())$ctime`
```

Assuming your markdown file is called `date.Rmd`.

Edited to add a more general method...

Comment: That is a helpful lead. All R Markdown templates are names skeleton.Rmd in R packages, so your code works while the template is named skeleton.Rmd, but once the template is saved under a new name (which is how all templates are used) the code no longer works without chaning the *.Rmd in file.info. Any further suggestions?

Comment: I updated with an alternative using `knitr::current_input()`

Comment: Thank you. `date: "\`r file.info(knitr::current_input())$ctime\`"` in the YAML works perfectly